# Docker socket override snap

Tags: snap, systemd, docker

If the Docker daemon is managed via `systemd` you can configure the settings for the socket by creating the file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.socket.d/override.conf` and adding some contents, example to set the owner group of the Unix socket file:

```
[Socket]
SocketGroup = my-new-docker-group
```

However, in Ubuntu 20.04 Docker is installed via snap (ie: `snap install docker`) and the `docker.socket` systemd unit does not exist and this approach does not work. How can I set the owner group of the socket in this case?

Comment: You can still install Docker with apt - [see here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

Comment: I cannot add new apt sources, it has to be from Snap